# Different order between nvidia-smi and nvidia x server settings

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, gpu, nvidia, pci-e

When I run the command `nvidia-smi`, I get the following two GPUs ordered by their Bus-Ids:

> For GPU 0, 00000000:0A:00.0
>
> For GPU 1, 00000000:41:00.0

However, when I run `NVIDIA X server Settings`, I can get the following GPUs ordered by their Bus-Ids:

> For GPU 0, PCI:65:0:0
>
> For GPU 1, PCI:10:0:0

Thus, they have different orders based on their own ways to enumerate Bus-Ids.
Is there any way to make the orders consistent?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Mainboard: MSI X399 (for AMD 1950X)

(PS)
In fact, my computer is freezed when using the [dataparallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html) mechanism for deep learning on multiple GPUs. I guess the different GPU orders are the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The order that matters is CUDA order.

You can [enumerate](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-enumeration) CUDA devices and see which one is which.

Then, you'll be able to run your program on the GPU that is not being used for display using [`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#cuda-visible-devices), [`cudaSetDevice()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g159587909ffa0791bbe4b40187a4c6bb) or [`cuCtxCreate()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html#group__CUDA__CTX_1g65dc0012348bc84810e2103a40d8e2cf)

Answer (score 0):

`nvidia-smi` uses the order in which GPUs are registered with the driver at boot time. CUDA uses fastest-first.